# Connection to SQL Server is failing from executable

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008

I have a windows Application written at C Sharp, which is updating data store in SQL server 2008. When I am running application from .Net, I have no issues. I compiled application and install on the same laptop. When I run exe file I am getting the following error: "System.Data.SqlException (0x80131904): A network-related or instance-specific error occured while-establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible". 
Why I can connect to SQL server from MS Visual Studio, and not able to make connection to SQL from executable file (same laptop) ?  Thank you.

Comment: Also check you have a connection string set somewhere, i.e. your app.config. Your error message appears to indicate that the connection being opened in code either has a bad connection string...or...the server IS inaccessible.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the config file where your SQL connection string should be stored is next to the `exe` file when you install your application.

Answer (score 1):

Please ensure that you have a file called "projectname.exe.config" right next to your exe. If so, then please ensure that you have the SQL connection string in this config file. If so, the please ensure that it is the correct connection string. Also, please ensure that the user account specified in the connection string has access to the DB. If you are using windows authentication (SSPI) then please ensure the your windows account has access to the DB.

NOTE: the config file name MUST be "exeName.exe.config". The exeName is usually the project name. Just in case you have changed the exe name from the default.

Hope this helps.

Comment: You just love _"please ensure"_. :) +1 for the steps to ensure.